# Rails: Determine when detached run is done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using Rails on Heroku together with the heroku-api gem.

On a scheduled basis I run a rake-script. I want to see the results of that script every time it runs:

```
require 'heroku-api' 
heroku = Heroku::API.new(:api_key => 'abc123')
feedback_str = ""
begin
  heroku.post_ps('myapp', "rake do_this_and_that", { :attach => false })
  feedback_str += "-- Rake result -> OK" + "<br /><br />"
rescue Exception => exc
  feedback_str += "-- Rake result -> Failed with error: " + exc.message + "<br /><br />"     
end

puts feedback_str
```

Now, this basically just tells me that the heroku.post_ps command executed fine. It doesn't really tell me if it crashed during its run (which I am interested in knowing).

My question now is what can I do to fetch the result (OK or Fail) from that detached rake run, after it is completed?